# It's possible to custumize the width of a TabBarPage in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, flutterflow

Please help, i need a `TabBar` with diferent sizes for `Tabs` and `TabBarPage`, meanning the `Tabs` width has to be: 100px, but the `TabBarPage` width has to be 100%, it's that possible? Thanks in advance.

[image]